# How to set default path that shows in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to change the url path on the web site.

For example when you develop webpage you have address like:

```
www.example.com/index.html
www.example.com/about_us.html
www.example.com/en/index.html
```

how to make this to be only

```
www.example.com
```

on every page that you visit...
But when you go to the next folder then it only needs to show the folder name and not page name, something like:

```
www.example.com/en/
```

Is there any script already written for that?

Comment: Do you mean `url rewriting`?

Comment: yea you could say it like that too

Answer (score 0):

this will be only doable though ajax calles

so for example if i were to click over the home button ,

```
$('.home').click(function(){
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.maincontainer').html(data); //populate the main container with the html of the other file

});
})
```

this will preserve the url form being changed ,
downsides being

1- if i want to give some body the link to your home page then i cant

2- google wont be able to crawl your site

and now i when he click over the change language (en)

then i will make a directory in the root folder and then when he clicks over the it the user will be redirected to that folder which have the same thing as above ..

or to avoid code double-cation i will make it appear as a get request , and if the get variable is set then you can switch the datasource to the appropriate file